# Python - Convenient way to check for a value in a list that is part of a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, include

I have admittedly not done a huge amount of research on this topic, but I am trying to get something done quickly. I have a dictionary with integers as keys and lists as values. Previously, I was checking for a list being in the dictionary with a simple if statement:

```
if(someList is in someDictionary.values()):
    someCode() #failure
```

However, I realized it is incorrect for what I was doing, and I only want to check for the inclusion of the first value of the list in the dictionary's values, e.g

```
if(someList[0] == someValueInDictionary[0]):
    someCode() #failure
```

I first tried

```
if(someList[0] is in someDictionary.values()[0]):
    someCode() #failure
```

But that clearly doesn't work. As someDictionary.values() is a list in itself. I realize I could iterate through all of the values to check, e.g

```
for list in someDictionary.values():
    if(someList[0] == list[0]):
        someCode() #failure
actualCode() #success
```

But this really messes up the flow of my program. I am a new Python programmer, most experienced in Java, and I am trying to get the conciseness and convenience of Python in my bones, as such I thought there might be a better solution for what I am testing for. If there is not, I can make the iteration thing work, but if there is, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression to find if there is any dictionary value that contains your item:

```
if any(someList[0] in v for v in someDictionary.itervalues()):
    # item found
```

Use `someDictionary.values()` on Python 3. The generator expression loops over the dictionary values (without producing a list of all values first) and tests against each value, one by one as the generator expression is iterated over.

`any()` only tests elements from the generator expression until one is `True`, and then stops looping, making this relatively efficient.

If you need to have the key of the matching value, use `next()`:

```
next((k for k, v in someDictionary.iteritems() if someList[0] in v), None)
```

which returns either the matching key, or `None` in no match is found.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters Actually, is there any way to get the key that triggered the true?

Comment: Dictionary key, or the list?

Comment: The list would be fine, because I could just do someDictionary.keys()[someDictionary.values().index(list)], but the goal is the dictionary key

Comment: I used a time machine and added the most efficient way to retrieve the key before you answered by comment. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming that you want to check the first element of `someList` against the first element in all of `someDictionary`'s list values (the code in the question seems to indicate that's what you want):

```
if someList[0] in (x[0] for x in someDictionary.itervalues()):
    someCode()
```

But if what you want is to check if the first element of `someList` is in *any* of the lists of values, then try this:

```
import itertools as it
if someList[0] in it.chain(*someDictionary.itervalues()):
    someCode()
```

Comment: I think you can change your list comprehension to a generator expression and `.values()` to `.itervalues()` to make it more efficient.

Comment: What about the gen expr. `1 in [x for x in xrange(10**7)]` _vs_ `1 in (x for x in xrange(10**7))` shows quite a difference.